# What is universal method for `get or default` in python?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, mongoengine

I would like to get an attribute of mongoengine model object but it's missing (how it's often in mongo):

`unit.city` gives me `AttributeError`

`unit.get('city')` says that `'Unit' object has no attribute 'get'` and I can't find any appropriate method by `dir(unit)`.

So I have to use standard python statement:

```
city = unit.city if 'city' in unit else None
```

That is a bit complex for just a `get` operation, because I have many transformations of that kind.

And so I wonder if there is any universal method for getting attribute value or some default value (if attribute doesn't exist) — such as `get` for `dict` type:

```
city = unit.get('city') # None
# or
city = unit.get('city', 'Moscow') # 'Moscow'
```

I would define my own function `get` but I'm interested if there is any in standard libraries. And yet, `from operation import getitem` doesn't able to do that.

I use python 2, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`getattr(object, name[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
city = getattr(unit, 'city', 'Moscow')
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i've been looking for.

Answer (score 3):

In general python, there are two common patterns. A mix of [hasattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr) + [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) or wrapping the whole thing in try / except

```
city = getattr(unit,'city','Moscow')
```

Other approach is

```
try:
    city = unit.city
except AttributeError:
    city = None
```

The second is argubly more pythonic. However when you are dealing with databases. It's better to use an ORM and avoid this sort of thing all together.

Comment: Missed one single quote in the first approach.

Comment: The second is certainly not "more pythonic" since the whole point of allowing a `default` argument to `getattr()` is to avoid the (potentially costly) exception handler.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers secondly is definitely more pythonic. https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html pythonic is not about what is more peformant and what is not.

Comment: Yes I know about the EAFP vs LBYL thing - but here by using `getattr()` with a default argument, we don't LBYL, we just make proper use of the language's features. It's just like using `dict.get()` vs catching a `KeyError`.

Comment: I think this is getting to be a matter of opinon. Let's agree to disagree

Comment: @e4c5 Thanks, that what I've been looking for.